# Программа, выводящая слова строки в обратном порядке на C++

Tags: c++, строки, циклы

Написал прогу, которая должна выводить слова строки в обратном порядке. Запускается без ошибок, даёт ввести строку, но не выводит ничего.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
    int i, k, a=0, dl=0;
    string str;
    cout << "Enter string:";
    dl=str.length();
    getline(cin,str);
    for(i=dl;i>=0;i--){
        a++;
        if(str[i]==' '){
            for(k=i;k<=(i+a);k++){
                cout << str[k];
             a=0;   
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- "а" считает длину каждого слова и сбрасывается после написания этого слова.
- Я новичок в программировании, если возможно, объясните попроще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
    int i, k, a=0, dl=0;
    string str;
    cout << "Enter string:";
    getline(cin, str);
    dl=str.length();
    for(i=dl;i>=0;i--){
        if(str[i] == ' '){
            for(k=i + 1;k<=(i+a);k++){
                cout << str[k];
            }
            a=0;
            cout  << " ";
        }
        
        a++;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < dl; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') break;
        cout << str[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```